# RazorGenerator not generating the correct namespace

Tags: asp.net, razorgenerator

We're using RazorGenerator for our project. When I edit views, the generated files' namespaces are changed to **ASP** instead of the RazorGenerator's default, which is supposed to be the folder structure. We didn't change any settings for RazorGenerator (not even sure if there are settings) so I'm not really sure what happened since this happens to my machine only. I already uninstalled/installed the tool but the same thing happens. Anybody have a solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hey i just had the same issue. According to this http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/workitem/166 you should create a file in your views folder called `razorgenerator.directives` and add in it the following:

> GeneratePrettyNames: true

and it will generate the correct namespace.

Comment: Thanks, @Stella Would you happen to know if it would work with 1.6.4? Apparently, I upgraded my version to 1.7 that's why this happens. But my teammates are using 1.6.4.

Comment: @dork, yes would work with 1.6.4. The change was made as part of 1.7